# Mapping an Image to show states of a country

Tags: html, html5-canvas, shapes

I was trying to make rectangles and polygons in **HTML5**, using area tag, as we know when ever we change position of any section or div or any changes we can see live. as we change, the same moment it shows the results (Using Chrome). But when i am trying to give different cords to RECT or POLY, the result doesn't show live, i have to click on screen somewhere else to see the resulting cords, that where they stand now
E.G

```
<map name="usaMap" id="usaMap">
  <area id="ak" shape="rect" coords="76,347,138,408" href="#" alt="Usa_map" />
</map>
```

now as i change the cords, i want the live changes in RECT, is it possible? in any browser or through any technique ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG seems to be a good solution for you.

There are many SVG maps of the states of the US freely available.

Each state is represented by a path--like a CSS area map.

But since each state path is a DOM element you can assign event handlers to these SVG paths which highlights individual states as the user hovers over each state.

You can also get any state path using CSS accessors and change that state's properties using javascript.  For example, you could programatically change Alaska's fill color to green.

Here's an example SVG map of the US that highlights each state on hover.

http://jqvmap.com/

I see you put the Html5-Canvas tag on your question. Here's an example that starts with an SVG map and draws the map on Canvas.

http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html